# Python/Pygame : "pygame.error: display Surface quit"

Tags: python, class, pygame

So, I'm making a game project, and I decided, for once, to make a custom class for my pygame window, like so :

```
class Screen(pygame.Surface):
    """Class for making a screen"""

    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int):
        """Screen Class Constructor"""
        self = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


    def _events(self):
        """Events Handler"""

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    def _fill(self, color):
        self.fill(color)
```

And, in the gameloop, I decided to make an instance of this class, and to call the

```
._fill()
```

method, like so :

```
# Importing
import pygame
import ScreenClass
import StaticsClass # Class with multiple colors

# Functions
def main():
    """Main function, where all the game happens.."""
    scr = ScreenClass.Screen(800, 600)
    print(type(scr))

    while True:
        scr._fill(StaticsClass.Color.BLACK0)
        scr._events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I try to run the main loop, it gives me this error message (that I never saw before) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\PYTHON\Jeux\A While Ago\mainloop.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\PYTHON\Jeux\A While Ago\mainloop.py", line 13, in main
    scr._fill(StaticsClass.Color.BLACK0)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\PYTHON\Jeux\A While Ago\ScreenClass.py", line 22, in _fill
    self.fill(color)
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

And, except maybe for THAT particular line :

```
self = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

I really don't know why it happens. Maybe it's because it's not possible to make a custom Screen class ?

So my question is : **Why is this happening ? If I can make a custom window class, how ? Because it doesn't seem to work...**

Any help would be greatly welcome!

EDIT 1: If you need the code of all the files, I will make them visible :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the parent class. Inside your init function.

```
def __init__(self, width: int, height: int):
    """Screen Class Constructor"""
    super().__init__((width, height))
    self = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```